# How to make tnethttpclient support socks 4/5 proxy delphi

Tags: sockets, proxy, privoxy

The tnethttpclient of the Net package does not support socks 4/5 proxies, what 
will be the possible approaches to add that support?

Comment: Without rewriting its internals, you will likely have to either 1) switch to another HTTP component, such as Indy's `TIdHTTP`, or any other 3rd-party HTTP implementation that supports proxies, or 2) write a custom HTTP server for `TNetHttpClient` to connect to, and then have that server tunnel connections through your Socks proxy as needed.

Comment: I need it for tnethttpclient have you custom HTTP server for TNetHttpClient?

Comment: No, I do not. You will have to make your own, such as with Indy's `TIdHTTPServer` or `TIdHTTPProxyServer` component, or find a 3rd party HTTP server that does what you need. And in the meantime, [file a feature request](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero to add proxy support to `TNetHTTPClient`.

Comment: Thank you verry match :)

Comment: I send it for Embarcadero

Comment: Even if this issue is old now: if you create a feature or bug request for something it is a good idea to post the report number, as others might be interested in that hing as well and can track it then.